# How to enable LogCat/Console in Eclipse for Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

While working on a simple program in Android, I mistakenly closed LogCat window and I want to know how to show it again.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

In Eclipse, Goto Window-> Show View -> Other -> Android-> Logcat.

Logcat is nothing but a console of your Emulator or Device.

`System.out.println` does not work in Android. So you have to handle every thing in Logcat. More Info Look out this [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html).

Edit 1: System.out.println is working on Logcat. If you use that the Tag will be like System.out and Message will be your message.

Comment: System.out.println does work in android and it apears as 'info' log

Answer (score 12):

Write "LogCat" in **Quick Access** edit box in your eclipse window (top right corner, just before Open Prospective button). And just select LogCat it will open-up the LogCat window in your current prospect

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In the `Window` menu, open `Show View` -> `Other ...` and type `log` to find it.

Answer (score 5):

In the "Window" menu, open "Open Perspective" -> "Debug".

[image]
click On the plus image icon(you see the below image at status bar), and then select "Logcat"....

Comment: Hi Paresh ,just cannot identify what u said yesterday,but now i saw it,Thanks a lot Paresh for showing the new  way

Answer (score 0):

Go to your desired perspective. Go to 'Window->show view' menu.

If you see logcat there, click it and you are done.

Else, click on 'other' (at the bottom), chose 'Android'->logcat.

Hope that helps :-)