# running logcat on Eclipse

Tags: java, android

I searched through whole internet but I still don't understand how I need to set up logCat what it would run. Could someone help with this?

Comment: Have you looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280051/how-to-enable-logcat-console-in-eclipse-for-android ?

Comment: whoops so your logcat is not running? can you descripe your problem a little more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the main menu, choose Window > Open Perspective > Other. In the dialog that appears, choose DDMS. LogCat will be the tool at the bottom of that perspective (by default -- you can reposition it).

Answer (score 0):

Logcat usage is tagbased. You develop your Application and when you want to log something you say:

```
Log.i("CUSTOM", "getting old data!");
```

then you go into Logcat and define a Custom Filter, there is an option to filter by *TAG*. This is the first parameter on your Log.i call, so for example you define a filter for your "CUSTOM"-Tag. Now you have a new tab in your logcat that holds all your CUSTOM-logmessages.

hope that helps

Comment: I can't really find where logcat is