# Use JSoup with Android Java

Tags: java, android, jsoup

```
package com.example.application;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import com.example.androidtablayout.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class PhotosActivity extends Activity  {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        String htmlCode = "";

            Document doc;
              try {
                  //Problem start
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com/").get();
            Element content = doc.select("a").first();
                    String variable = content.text();
                  // Problem end
                    TextView t = new TextView(this);
                    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3); 
                    t.setText(variable);
               } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
            }

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.photos_layout);

    }
}
```

My problem is with JSoup framework.  Between of "Problem" lines. I take the "Unexpectedly Stopped Error".

When I put the "htmlCode" variable like this

```
t.SetText(htmlCode);
```

It is work but  i get all of html source code .

What is the main problem , i can't get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot wrong with your code:

- `super.onCreate()` should always be the very first call in your own `onCreate()`
- You call `setContentView()` at the very end but try to `findViewById()` before that in the catch clause. At that point, your `Activity` has no content view yet, so `findViewById()` will return `null` -- the resulting `NullPointerException` is most likely why your code crashes.
- You do IO on the UI thread. Don't do that, Android will force-quit your app because IO is unpredictable and your app will be unresponsive, this is even worse with network IO. Check out [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#AsyncTask) on how to do IO off the UI thread and then asynchronously update your `TextView`.

Also, check out [logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3280126/180740). For most crashes, it will contain a stacktrace that will pinpoint where things went wrong.

---

Here's a reworked version of your code that follows some of the advice I've given.

Please note that I did **not** have the time to **fix the most important issue**: This code still does IO on the UI thread. It should use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#AsyncTask) instead!

```
public class PhotosActivity extends Activity {

  // Use a string constant to "tag" log statements that belong to the same
  // feature/module of your app. This activity does something with "photos" so
  // use that as a tag. It's the first parameter to Android's Log methods.
  private static final String TAG = "photos";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call super.onCreate() first.
    setContentView(R.layout.photos_layout); // Then load the layout.

    // Find textView3 in layout and set it's text to HTML code.
    // There's no need to create a new TextView() here.
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textView.setText(getHtmlCode());
  }

  // Structure your code. If it's a larger block that does one thing,
  // extract it into a method.
  private String getHtmlCode() {
    try {
      Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com/").get();
      Element content = doc.select("a").first();
      return content.text();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // Never e.printStackTrace(), it cuts off after some lines and you'll
      // lose information that's very useful for debugging. Always use proper
      // logging, like Android's Log class, check out
      // http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html
      Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load HTML code", e);
      // Also tell the user that something went wrong (keep it simple,
      // no stacktraces):
      Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load HTML code",
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Phillipp. Thanks for answer. The point of i don't understand, when I delete between //problem start and // problem end and put the string variable at "setText()" I take the variable at the my layout. 
Should I work out of onCreate event ? Did you mean ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment at all. I've quickly reworked your code and added it to my question -- I hope this helps. Please note that the code still does not use `AsyncTask`, but it should!

Comment: Thanks Phillip! I worked for 2 days for this code. I understand my all mistakes. Thanks again :)

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot, please post a new question, include your code and the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

You should move your call `super.onCreate(...)` and `setContentView(...)` to the first two lines in your onCreate method.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.photos_layout);
  .....
```