# I need help adding Thread to the connection of web service or it will not run

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a call to a web service when I click the button, the button part and input works now i am trying to actually call web service, but i need Threads to do so, but i don't know them. People are saying to use AsyncTask.

**LogCat log for callWS:**
**callWS:** "http://pastebin.com/nuLnPQz8"

**callWS FUNCTION::**
It will allways crash because it requires Threads.

**XML Code:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Pošlji "
        android:onClick = "callWS"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Text1"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Text1"
        android:text="Output: "
        tools:context=".Activity123" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity123.java code:**

```
package com.test123;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.test123.R;

public class Activity123 extends Activity 
   {
      private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://192.168.0.25/webapplication1/ws.asmx";
      private static final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";
      private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://microsoft.com/webservices/";
      private static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.25/webapplication1/ws.asmx?WSDL";
      /** Called when the activity is first created. */

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
         {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity123);
         }

      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
         {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_activity123, menu);
            return true;
         }

  public void TEST(View button_one)
     {
        //int a = 2 + 3; // Runs fine
        //TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output); // TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_one); // Runs fine
        //text.setText(String.valueOf(a)); IGNORE THIS ABOVE SECTION

        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Text1); // et is our editText 
        String input = et.getText().toString(); // 

        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output); 
        text.setText( String.valueOf(input) ); 
        //setContentView(R.layout.secondary_activity);

        klicWS(input);
     }  

        public void klicWS(String input) // We receive input variable from TEST
           {
              //Thread networkThread = new Thread(); Threads like this... but this ain't correct....

              SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);                       
              SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
              envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
              envelope.dotNet = true;
              envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;

              HttpTransportSE HT = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

              try 
                 {
                    HT.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                    //Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse(); // maybe important ?

                       {
                          TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
                          text.setText( "Message from WS: "+response.toString()  );

                          //TextView tv = new TextView(this); this is from an example
                          //tv.setText( "Message :"+response.toString() ); // from example
                          setContentView(R.layout.secondary_activity); // The second one...
                       }
                 } 

             catch (Exception e) 
                {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
     }
```

}

**SCREENSHOT OF STUFF INSIDE IDE(Eclipse), alongside that strings.xml for assistance:** 
http://www.filedropper.com/ideplusstringsxml
[image]

Comment: Please can you put those files somewhere like pastebin? I can't actually view them to help you without signing up at 4shared. Here is a link for you: http://pastebin.com/ Thanks!

Comment: Updated the logs, but for the screenshot i forgot the name of website i use that USED TO not require anything at all, but now it needs a simple login and it's great... it's something+shared +sharing...

Anyone know a good image share website ?

Comment: Tried imgur.com, but it just stops at 13% in firefox and at 0% on explorer...

Comment: DONE http://www.filedropper.com/ideplusstringsxml

Comment: I guess ill have to create another question... all answers in first hour then nothing for next 2...

Comment: Oh come on people... i can't re-ask...

Comment: Please someone help me out... i need this done really... im desperate...

Comment: I tried to edit your question, but you better edit it again to show only the not solved yet problems, with the related errors from [logcat](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3280126/469983).

Comment: I made some progress on my own yeh... WHAT I NEED now is the THREAD part... i got no idea... this tutorial does not help me http://javatutorialspoint.blogspot.com/2012/02/android-web-service-access-using-ksoap2.html cause... it's outdated.

Ok ill edit

Comment: well i edited this yesterday already, but website often goes page not found after doing it...

Comment: Noone is gona see this anyways, since it's not on any kind of front page... ill just stay at 1 single 100 line program for a week...

Comment: I think i edited somewhere like that... -.-

Comment: Others ask for entire 100 + lines of code, and i just want it threaded and that's such a problem ? Well that's extremely rude.

Comment: And that change wasn't mine, eclipse acts weird everyhere and then, does stuff on it's own... Also log cat isn't relevant anymore, we aren't searching for an error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common mistake. You call the TextView's setText method with an integer argument

```
int a = 2 + 3; // Runs fine
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_one); 
text.setText(a); // makes ERROR
```

The setText method with an integer argument is designed to take a resource ID (R.string.some_string_key).

That is why the logs says

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String
>   resource ID #0x5

You try to get a String from strings.xml from the generated R.java file with an ID of 5

Just replace the line that fails with

```
text.setText(String.valueOf(a)); // should work
```

Comment: No problem. This is why your app crashes.

Comment: I was 3 days hitting the wall with these problems... i will continue doing so until this app is finished and works connecting to any WS, god im just 17 and he got me that to do... (he got a PhD... )

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this line.

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_one);
```

You convert your BUTTON button_one to a TEXTVIEW. I don't know if this is possible.

Try to use

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
```

and test if your code would work.

Comment: No the same... (someone doesn't like me that's why <.<)

Comment: Button Extends TextView, so the cast should be fine http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: Now i only got callWH + Celsium to Fe... left to do.

Comment: Looks like setText don't like int values. You can solve this like this text.setText(a + ""); quick and easy;

Answer (score 0):

When the button is clicked you are trying to do some network related operations. In Android, any network related operations should not be done in the main UI thread.

So on the button click either start a new thread and get the information from network or use Async Task.

Thanks & Regards,
Rajamanickem. S

Comment: This is true, but not relevant.

Comment: And can i get some link or tutorial somewhere... cause i got no brain for android java... i just want this app done and never come back <.<.

Comment: Can i please get to know how to do this ?