# Android app force closing

Tags: android

I'm new to Android app development and Java in general. I have been watching some tutorials but decided it was time to start doing something on my own. I'm trying to make a fat caliper calculator where I insert all the info in one activity, calculate it and then pass the results on to another activity for displaying it. For some reason I'm getting a force close every time I hit the calculate button and I'm not sure what's causing it or which activity.

Here's the code:

[MainActivity](http://pastebin.com/1G0MVPBL)

[Display](http://pastebin.com/jTGbJk6c)

Can you see what's causing the force closes?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the logcat output which will display the error as to why it force closed.

Comment: You are new to android you say. I guess you work with eclipse? If I remember good, it doesn't start Logcat automatically, here is how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280051/how-to-enable-logcat-console-in-eclipse-for-android
Then post that info here too

Comment: The right answer is below, I forgot to putExtras into the Intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are starting display Activity but not passing bundle to the Display Activity.

Change your code like this when you are starting Display Activity.

```
Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Display.class);
a.putExtras("giveResults",packet );
startActivity(a);
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved it! Now to remember to putExtras next time I need to :P

Answer (score 1):

I believe its because where you are starting your activity, and your bundle, your not adding the bundle to the intent.

You would need to do something like

```
a.putExtra(packet)
```

before you start the activity

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer.  It describes LogCat which is the best way to debug android code.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3280126/771999

If you use LogCat you can usually pinpoint the exact line number of your issue.