# sending datas from jsp to android

Tags: android, jsp

in **jsp** after insertion i'm sending success or failure to android using the following code

```
 response.setContentType("text/html");
 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
 oos.writeObject("success");
 out.print("success");
```

in **android** i receive the datas using the following code

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mysite.com.au/validation1.jsp");
List<NameValuePair> namevaluepairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pin",pass));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevaluepairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity rp = response.getEntity();
String origresponseText =  EntityUtils.toString(rp);
String responseText = origresponseText.substring(7, origresponseText.length());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incoming data-->"+responseText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if(responseText.equals("success")){
// do something
}
```

**IS THERE ANY DRAWBACKS IN RECEIVING DATAS FROM JSP TO ANDROID USING THIS CODE**

My application works perfectly in my mobile i.e sony xperia....but the same application is not responding  in some other phones not all....can anyone please tell me what's the reason behind that

Comment: post logcat stack trace

Comment: Have you tried using JSON to transfer data to the android device.

Comment: are u doing this on the main thread or an async. Connect your phn or emulator, run the app, then in see the logs in logcat. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280051/how-to-enable-logcat-console-in-eclipse-for-android

Comment: sir in emulator its working and also in some of the android phones....but in some it not responding