# why program show invocationtargetexception when i want to go second activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

in my project first i find the user location and then i want open new activity and show user location on the map but when program want to read the thired lind program go to the debug mode and show invocationtargetexception ...? why program show this ? 
in secend activity i use the fragmentactivity ..

```
double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            Intent is = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Location_find.class);
                is.putExtra("latitude",String.valueOf( latitude));
                is.putExtra("longitude",String.valueOf( longitude));
                startActivity(is);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `getBaseContext()`. Instead use your `Activity Context`. Change it to

```
Intent is = new Intent(ActivityName.this, Location_find.class);
```

If this doesn't help then please post your logcat.

Comment: it doesnt work. i am new in android and i dont know how i can find logcat

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: [See this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280051/how-to-enable-logcat-console-in-eclipse-for-android) then post your logcat

Comment: in logcat only show 09-25 02:45:25.515: I/System.out(5832): >>>>>>label name::Sayna
09-25 02:45:28.370: I/System.out(5832): >>>>>>label name::Sayna

Comment: and in debug window Thread [<1> main] (Suspended) 
 ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1041 
 ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 805 
 NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]

Comment: Filter your logcat by "error". If it crashed then there will be more information.

Comment: i try to open new easy activity without any thing and it is work but when i chang it to extended fragmentactivity and again read same line to open new activity i see same exception...

Comment: this is error that i see in log cat 09-25 03:23:17.435: E/AndroidRuntime(29978): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.home.sayna.Location_find

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to list any activities you use in your app in the app's AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: i think maybe this is my problem but no . in first line witout go to line startactivity() i see this exception