# android-forceclose using timer

Tags: java, android, timer, forceclose

my application force closes but compiler doesn't show any errors at all
i have provided the code

```
 package my.android;

package com.google.android.gms.auth.sample.helloauth;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class HelloActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    int time;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        time = 0;
        Timer t = new Timer();

        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

                        tv.setText(time);
                        time += 1;
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 10000);
    }
}
```

Comment: if the application closes. it will be a message in the logcat. please post it

Comment: Check this link enable logcat using eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280051/how-to-enable-logcat-console-in-eclipse-for-android

Answer (score 0):

SetText method asks for a String parameter. Try this

```
tv.setText(String.valueOf(time));
```

Answer (score 0):

move this line before creating the object of timer `after setContentView(R.layout.main);`

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
```

and change

```
tv.setText(time);
```

to

```
tv.setText(String.valueOf(time));
```

coz setText() always takes `String` as a parameter u r passing an `int` thats why facing force close