# Error when I switch Android activities

Tags: android

So I am working on an app and my app keeps stopping unexpectedly. Here is my code and manifest file:

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.lasic;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void goNext(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,QuestionActivity.class));
    }

}
```

**QuestionActivity**

```
package com.example.lasic;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuestionActivity extends Activity{
    private int counter = 1;
    private UserScanner scanner = new UserScanner();
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firstq);
        loadNext();
    }
    public void loadNext() {
        TextView view1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        view1.setText(scanner.questionList.get(counter));
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setText(scanner.left.get(counter));
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setText(scanner.centerLeft.get(counter));
        Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setText(scanner.center.get(counter));
        Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setText(scanner.centerRight.get(counter));
        Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button5.setText(scanner.right.get(counter));
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
}
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lasic"
    android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <application
        android:debuggable = "true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.lasic.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
          android:name="com.example.lasic.QuestionActivity" 
          android:label="EntrySurvey" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

When I try to switch from `MainActivity` to `QuestionActivity` using `goNext()` method, I get "this app stopped unexpectedly error". How do I fix this please?

Comment: could you post LOGCAT errors ?

Comment: Where is the logcat error?

Comment: In your logcat.  If you run adb logcat at a command line or look at the logcat tab in Eclipse you can see the log.  It will have a full stack trace with the exception and context there.

Comment: I'm assuming it is a problem with your `UserScanner` class.  You sure it is initialized before going into your `loadNext()` method?  For getting LogCat up and running - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280051/how-to-enable-logcat-console-in-eclipse-for-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Try This 
in goNext method

```
{

     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this ,QuestionActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);

}
```

And in manifest file just give
 `android:name=".QuestionActivity"`  is enough

Comment: You should clean up your answer some. Only put code in the code blocks and explain *what* you have changed and *why* you believe it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any error in this line:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,QuestionActivity.class));
```

It is correct. Are you sure there is not any error in your layout file? For example when you are not define  android:layout_width or android:layout_height for the button you may get "this app stopped unexpectedly error". So check your layout file.