# Android SDK Emulator

Tags: android

I'making an app that calculates a resistor value based on inputed band colours, it's name is 'resistorvalue'.
The platform I'm using is Eclipse.
When I run the program as an android application to the Android SDK Virtual emulator & clicked on the app within the emulator, it says: "unfortunately resistorvalue has stopped working".
I have the option of clicking ok or report.
I've ran other app that I've made and they work fine, I've no errors in my code. Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

Comment: What does LogCat tell you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280051/how-to-enable-logcat-console-in-eclipse-for-android or http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLogging/article.html has pictures and ways how to show that window in case you don't know what it is.