# Start Activity with MapFragment from another Activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-android-api-2, mapfragment

I developed an application and I need to start a new activity from my menu with a simple button. I made several tests and noticed that if I set the intent-filter of Activity that contains the MapFragment as follows:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

this works fine without any crashes.
If instead modify the intent-filter in such a way as not to start the Activity soon as you open the app and in particular the edit as follows:

```
 <action android:name="com.hpdev.maps.MYMAP" />

 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

The activity is not started and the app crashes. How can I fix this bug? 
I include the code in my activity.java:

```
public class MyMap extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

}}
```

My stacktrace:

```
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889): Process: com.fziviello.altamuragroup, PID: 28889
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fziviello.altamuragroup/com.fziviello.altamuragroup.DoveSono}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2227)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5088)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:547)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:344)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1952)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at com.fziviello.altamuragroup.DoveSono.onCreate(DoveSono.java:37)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5434)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2181)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    ... 12 more
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4816)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    ... 25 more
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.fziviello.altamuragroup-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.fziviello.altamuragroup-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:583)
04-03 20:49:57.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28889):    ... 28 more
```

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3280126/2668136

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is start a new `Activity` from a button, just create an `Intent` that explicitly points to that `Activity` in the button's onClickListener. The below is an onClickListener defined in a `Fragment`'s button:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MapActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

You need to make sure that all of you `Activity`'s are registered in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, but they don't all require intent filters. You will need the Main/ Launcher intent filter in the `Activity` that you want the launcher icon to open, but other `Activities` don't require intent filters because you can explicitly reference them as I dide in the code above.

Comment: I've already tried this approach but it does not solve the problem

Comment: Harry, it looks like this line of your stacktrace points out the culprit: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.fziviello.altamuragroup-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.fziviello.altamuragroup-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]. Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio? If using Android Studio, you need to make sure your dependencies include Google Play Services.

Comment: Justin I use Eclipse, in any case, this is not the problem. If I change the intent-filter works perfectly, all imported libraries are already up and running.

Comment: The last thing I can think of at the moment is to try the code in my original answer, but remove the intent filter for MapActivity from your manifest. If that doesn't work, is your code on Github? Unfortunately, I'm out of ideas without seeing the actual project ...